# Filter Matching String Lines in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to force my text output to ignore certain lines.  My current command is:

```
type "C:\file.txt" | findstr "COMPANY:
```

and it outputs with:

```
COMPANY:  
COMPANY:  
COMPANY:  
COMPANY:  Company1
COMPANY:  Company2
COMPANY:  Company3
COMPANY:  
COMPANY:  
COMPANY:
```

Is it possible to ignore the blank lines?  I've tried `findstr /v "COMPANY:` , but that just removes everything.  :(

What I want the output to be is:

```
COMPANY:  Company1
COMPANY:  Company2
COMPANY:  Company3
```

Comment: `findstr /ric:"Company: *[^ ]" "filename.txt"` -- see `findstr /?` in a cmd console for full syntax and details.  That'll perform a case-insensitive regex search for lines containing "company:" followed by zero or more spaces, followed by at least one non-space character.

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thank you!